# 'MySQL STR_TO_DATE with no day in the string

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I am trying to use `STR_TO_DATE` in my MySQL code, but my string does not include a day.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('August 2020', '%M %Y')
```

This code returns null. I can get this function to work if I have a day in my date like:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('August 20, 2020', '%M %d, %Y')
```

Is it because I'm formatting it wrong? Or does MySQL not support this functionality? If it doesn't support it is there a way around it?

[image: Image of it shown in DBeaver]

Comment: This is working fine : SELECT STR_TO_DATE('August 2020', '%M %Y')
returning - 2020-08-00.

Comment: I added an image above showing that I tried that same line and it still returned [NULL]

Comment: It seems the format is working with version 5.6 but with latest version 8.0.13 it's not working.